# How to use Contact Form 7 to handle the server side mail() only?

Tags: wp-mail, plugin-contact-form-7

How can I use [Contact Form 7](https://contactform7.com/) to do the `mail()` **server side** only and I handle the **client side** myself?

I have this form that uses Zurb Foundation to validate the submission:

```
<form class="form-comment form-submit" id="formComment" data-abide novalidate action="" data-aos="fade-up">

     <!-- grid container -->
     <div class="grid-container">

        <!-- grid x -->
        <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">

            <div class="medium-12 cell">
                <div data-abide-error class="alert callout" style="display: none;">
                    <p><i class="fi-alert"></i> There are some errors in your form.</p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="medium-6 cell">
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="author" class="form-input" placeholder="Name" required>
                    <span class="form-error">Yo, you had better fill this out, it's required.</span>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="medium-6 cell">
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-input" placeholder="Phone number" pattern="UK_number_only">
                    <span class="form-error">Yo, UK landline or mobile numbers only.</span>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="medium-12 cell">
                <label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-input" placeholder="Email" pattern="email" required>
                    <span class="form-error">Yo, you had better fill this out, it's required. Or, it is invalid.</span>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="medium-12 cell">
                <label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Message" name="comment" class="form-input" rows="10" required></textarea>
                    <span class="form-error">Yo, you had better fill this out, it's required.</span>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="medium-12 cell">
                <input type="submit" class="button button-send float-right" value="Send">
                <input type="hidden" name="task" value="comment" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</form>

<div class="reveal" id="reveal1" data-reveal>
    <!-- Content will be loaded here from somwhere else, crazy! -->
    <h3>Loading...</h3>
</div>
```

JS:

```
Foundation.Abide.defaults.patterns['UK_number_only'] = /^(((\(?0\d{4}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|(\(?0\d{3}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|(\(?0\d{2}\)?\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?|(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})$/

  // Must call it after the pattern.
  $(document).foundation()

  // Submit message form.
  // http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/37267-foundation-6-abide-trigger-without-submit-button
  var form = $("form.form-submit")
  form.bind("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("submit intercepted")
    return false
  })
  form.bind("forminvalid.zf.abide", function(e,target) {
    console.log("form is invalid")
  })

  form.bind("formvalid.zf.abide", function(e,target) {
    console.log("form is valid")

    var param = target.serialize()
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: target.attr('action'),
      data: param,
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          // Clear the form.
          target.find("input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea").val("")

          $('#reveal1').foundation('open')

          // Artificially slow down load to let you see the loading state
          setTimeout(function() {
              $('#reveal1').html(responseData)
              $('#reveal1').trigger('resizeme.zf.reveal')
          }, 500)

          // Foundation Reveal - trigger reveal.
          // http://zurb.com/university/lessons/ajaxing-dynamic-content-with-foundation
          $('#reveal1').foundation('open')
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(errorThrown)
      }
    })
  })
```

How can use the code I have above with Contact Form 7? Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you _need_ to use Contact Form 7 instead of just using `wp_mail()` or `mail()`? As it stands this question will probably be closed as Off-Topic since it required specific knowledge of a 3rd party plugin. Please [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more.

Comment: my client wants to use it as it can store the messages with another add-on....

Comment: It's probably going to be much easier to look into how the add-on handles submissions and hook into that instead. This is pure speculation but if it's storing messages it's probably doing so by using Post Types and Postmeta which you can create and add upon submission to take advantage of add-on features. Contact Form 7 can be rigid sometimes when wanting to do really custom stuff.